# Updating existing records and adding new records in table (MS Access VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access

I can't get my code to add new records and update existing records in the table I have. I have two tables; one temporary table (tblTempData) and another table (tblCommon). I would like for the code to check if records exist, then update columns & if record is new then add new record. When I run the code, tblCommon is empty. I don't know which part is wrong. Would be thankful for guidance and advice.

Below is my code:

```
    Dim rsTemp As DAO.Recordset
    Dim rsCommon As DAO.Recordset

    Dim id1 As String
    Dim id2 As String

    Set rsTemp = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblTempData", dbOpenDynaset)
    Set rsCommon = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblCommon", dbOpenDynaset)

    rsTemp.MoveFirst
        id1 = rsTemp![Item ID]
    rsTemp.MoveNext

    Do Until rsTemp.EOF
        id2 = rsTemp![Item ID]
        If id1 = id2 Then
            With rsCommon
                If .RecordCount = 0 Then
                    .AddNew
                        ![Item Description] = rsTemp![Item Description]
                        ![Material Number] = rsTemp![Material Number]
                        ![User] = rsTemp![User]
                        ![Supplier] = rsTemp![Supplier]
                        ![Current Status] = rsTemp![Current Status]
                        ![Remarks] = rsTemp![Remarks]
                        ![Item ID] = id2
                    .Update
                    .Close
                Else
                    .FindFirst "[Item ID] = '" & id2 & "'"
                    If .NoMatch Then
                        .AddNew
                            ![Item Description] = rsTemp![Item Description]
                            ![Material Number] = rsTemp![Material Number]
                            ![User] = rsTemp![User]
                            ![Supplier] = rsTemp![Supplier]
                            ![Current Status] = rsTemp![Current Status]
                            ![Remarks] = rsTemp![Remarks]
                            ![Item ID] = id1
                        .Update
                        .Close
                    Else
                        .Edit
                            ![Item Description] = rsTemp![Item Description]
                            ![Material Number] = rsTemp![Material Number]
                            ![User] = rsTemp![User]
                            ![Supplier] = rsTemp![Supplier]
                            ![Current Status] = rsTemp![Current Status]
                            ![Remarks] = rsTemp![Remarks]
                            ![Item ID] = id2
                        .Update
                        .Close
                    End If
                End If
            End With
        Else
            Exit Sub
        End If
        id1 = id2
        rsTemp.MoveNext
    Loop
    Set rsTemp = Nothing
Else
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Thanks

Comment: [How to debug VBA code](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx) <-- please read and apply, you'll find out what is going on with id1 and id2.

Comment: The link gave me a 404 Error. Do you perhaps have other links to sites I can refer to? Thanks.

Comment: :( :( :( -- Chip Pearson's site cpearson.com was an invaluable resource. I fear the worst: http://www.kccremation.com/ObituaryDetails.aspx?id=23658

Comment: Please use web archive or google "debugging vba".

Comment: @Andre  That's very recent - I was last on there two days ago.

Comment: How sad. thank goodness for the wayback machine. https://web.archive.org/web/20171013032145/http://www.cpearson.com/excel/DebuggingVBA.aspx . I wonder if there's a way we can archive his information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An alternative approach.

Try to break down your code by creating a helper function for each task, `Exists()`, `Add()` and `Update()`. It will be easier to read and maintain the code.

- The first method checks if the record exists.
- The second updates the record.
- The third adds the record.

---

```
Option Explicit

Private rsCommon As DAO.Recordset

Public Sub UpdateExistingRecords()
    On Error GoTo ErrTrap

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblTempData", dbOpenSnapshot)
    Set rsCommon = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblCommon", dbOpenDynaset)

    Dim idx As Long
    For idx = 1 To rs.RecordCount
        If ExistsInCommon(rs![Item ID]) Then
            If Not Update(rs) Then
                MsgBox "Failed to update.", vbExclamation
                GoTo Leave
            End If
        Else
            If Not Add(rs) Then
                MsgBox "Failed to add.", vbExclamation
                GoTo Leave
            End If
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Next

Leave:
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then rs.Close
    If Not rsCommon Is Nothing Then rsCommon.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set rsCommon = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrTrap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub
```

---

```
' Exists - 'Assumes Id is String
Private Function ExistsInCommon(ByVal Id As String)
    ExistsInCommon = DCount("*", "tblCommon", "[Item ID] = '" & Id & "'") > 0   
End Function
```

---

```
' Update
Private Function Update(rs As DAO.Recordset) As Boolean
    With rsCommon
        .FindFirst "[Item ID] = '" & rs![Item ID] & "'"
        If .NoMatch Then Exit Function
        .Edit
        ![Item Description] = rs![Item Description]
        ![Material Number] = rs![Material Number]
        ![User] = rs![User]
        ![Supplier] = rs![Supplier]
        ![Current Status] = rs![Current Status]
        ![Remarks] = rs![Remarks]
        .Update
        .MoveFirst
    End With
    Update = True
End Function
```

---

```
'Add
Private Function Add(rs As DAO.Recordset) As Boolean
    With rsCommon
        .AddNew
        ![Item Description] = rs![Item Description]
        ![Material Number] = rs![Material Number]
        ![User] = rs![User]
        ![Supplier] = rs![Supplier]
        ![Current Status] = rs![Current Status]
        ![Remarks] = rs![Remarks]
        ![Item ID] = rs![Item ID]
        .Update
    End With
    Add = True
End Function
```

Comment: I don't quite understand this line:  ExistsInCommon = DCount("*", "tblCommon", "[Item ID] = '" & Id & "'") > 0.                                                                                                  
Why must the value of DCount be more than 0?

Comment: This function checks if the supplied Id exists in the table. If it exists the `DCount` returns 1 (or more) and if not, it returns 0. So this is our driver to see if we need to update (exists) or add (doesn't exist).

Comment: The statement `DCount("*", "tblCommon", "[Item ID] = '" & Id & "'") > 0` is a boolean evaluation of True or False where greater than 0 returns True.

Comment: So if we break it down it will be down to `1 > 0` (true) or `0 > 0` (false) since the `Dcount` function returns a number (count).