# IF 'x' matches 'y' then Merge With Existing Else Create New

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to import 'contacts' into my database from several external sources.

Some 'contacts' may already exist so I only need 'new' data.

I've written an update records code however it will overwrite all data therefore damaging the integrity of the table as the old data may contain some valid values.

***I tried using an update/append query however this only OVERWROTE the values of the original field not UPDATED IF OLD VALUE WAS NULL/FALSE ONLY. The issue with this is it will apply/remove profile flags that result in correspondence and data usage (Incorrect update = potential breach of GDPR).***

I can't program in SQL, I understand how the functions work and what they do but not how to compile/what order (yet) hence using VBA for now.

```
Dim myR As Recordset
Dim myR2 As Recordset

Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Staging - Import", dbOpenDynaset)
Set myR2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Contacts", dbOpenDynaset)

Do Until myR.EOF = True
    myR2.FindFirst ("Email = '" & myR![Email] & "'")
    If myR2.NoMatch = True Then
        myR2.AddNew
        myR2![Email] = myR![Email]
        myR2![First Name] = myR![First Name]
        myR2![Last Name] = myR![Last Name]
        myR2![Position] = myR![Position]
        myR2![Company] = myR![Company]
        myR2![Industry] = myR![Industry]
        myR2![Size] = myR![Size]
        myR2![Website] = myR![Website]
        myR2![Location] = myR![Location]
        myR2![Office Number] = myR![Office Number]
        myR2![Mobile Number] = myR![Mobile Number]
        myR2![Source] = myR![Source]
        myR2![CFO-DEL] = myR![CFO-DEL]
        myR2![CFO-SPON] = myR![CFO-SPON]
        myR2![DP-DEL] = myR![DP-DEL]
        myR2![DP-SPON] = myR![DP-SPON]
        myR2![HR-DEL] = myR![HR-DEL]
        myR2![HR-SPON] = myR![HR-SPON]
        myR2![CIO-DEL] = myR![CIO-DEL]
        myR2![CIO-SPON] = myR![CIO-SPON]
        myR2![CMO-DEL] = myR![CMO-DEL]
        myR2![CMO-SPON] = myR![CMO-SPON]
        myR2![CISO-DEL] = myR![CISO-DEL]
        myR2![CISO-SPON] = myR![CISO-SPON]
        myR2![NIS] = myR![NIS]
        myR2![Supress] = myR![Surpress]
        myR2.Update
    Else
        myR2.Edit
        myR2![First Name] = myR![First Name]
        myR2![Last Name] = myR![Last Name]
        myR2![Position] = myR![Position]
        myR2![Company] = myR![Company]
        myR2![Industry] = myR![Industry]
        myR2![Size] = myR![Size]
        myR2![Website] = myR![Website]
        myR2![Location] = myR![Location]
        myR2![Office Number] = myR![Office Number]
        myR2![Mobile Number] = myR![Mobile Number]
        myR2![Source] = myR![Source]
        myR2![CFO-DEL] = myR![CFO-DEL]
        myR2![CFO-SPON] = myR![CFO-SPON]
        myR2![DP-DEL] = myR![DP-DEL]
        myR2![DP-SPON] = myR![DP-SPON]
        myR2![HR-DEL] = myR![HR-DEL]
        myR2![HR-SPON] = myR![HR-SPON]
        myR2![CIO-DEL] = myR![CIO-DEL]
        myR2![CIO-SPON] = myR![CIO-SPON]
        myR2![CMO-DEL] = myR![CMO-DEL]
        myR2![CMO-SPON] = myR![CMO-SPON]
        myR2![CISO-DEL] = myR![CISO-DEL]
        myR2![CISO-SPON] = myR![CISO-SPON]
        myR2![NIS] = myR![NIS]
        myR2![Supress] = myR![Surpress]
        myR2.Update
    End If
    myR.MoveNext

Loop

Set myR = Nothing

End Sub
```

Is there a simpler way to write this or should I be utilising the code

```
    myR2.FindFirst ("Email = '" & myR![Email] & "'")
    If myR2.NoMatch = True Then
```

For each value, creating effectively 15-20 subs and a macro to run all together?

I tried several code variations attempting to include elseIf, isNull() and isFalse() however they always failed to compile or no update was completed/records changed.

I need the code to do the following:

1. Check the contact exists in contacts table
2. If contact does not exist, add all data
3. If contact does exist, add new data or update yes/no fields from no to yes

**NOTE:** Currently 'contacts' table is empty as we need to create new/merge duplicates before the data is imported to the 'contacts' table.

So Contacts is currently:

```
    Email   Name    Surname
    -       -       -
    -       -       -
    -       -       -
    -       -       -
```

Staging - Import is currently:

```
    Email   Name    Surname
    b@b.c   Brad    
    t@b.c   Tony    Tiger
    b@b.c   B       Pitt
    r@b.c   Ryan    Reynolds
```

Contacts should look like this after completed:

```
    Email   Name    Surname
    t@b.c   Tony    Tiger
    b@b.c   Brad    Pitt
    r@b.c   Ryan    Reynolds
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041105/updating-existing-records-and-adding-new-records-in-table-ms-access-vba/50042120#50042120

Comment: Thanks for the reply, After stressing for the last hour I had a similar idea to that however the unique identifier for me is 'email' and not a numerical value and for whatever reason just refuses to work or reverts to amending all values not just the new ones.

Comment: Clarity, many of the fields I'm updating are yes/no fields. After running the update a lot of the fields that should be yes is updated to no as this is the new/last value. I need to ensure that it only updates those fields if true (yes)

Comment: `myR2![Supress] = myR![Surpress]` - is one or both of these field names misspelled? The correct spelling is `Suppress` if the intended meaning is `to prevent`.

Comment: Yes that column was incorrectly spelt however that incorrect spelling was in all areas, I have now changed the spelling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Determining what to update or add when comparing string data can be quite complicated and often involves case-by-case review. What rule should be applied to program decision to take "Brad" from one record and "Pitt" from other? What if data for the same email were: `Brad Pitt` and `Bradley Pitt`? Which is correct and should be saved? Probably have to do a query that finds duplicate emails in Staging and make case-by-case decision on what to fix/delete for these duplicates. Then insert to Contacts. Insert code can test content of each field for Null or False and determine whether to accept new value.

For non-yes/no field, use Nz() function (assumes text field will not have empty string)
`myR2![First Name] = Nz(myR2![First Name], myR![First Name])`
or (to deal with possible empty string)
`If myR2![First Name] & "" = "" Then myR2![First Name] = myR![First Name]`
(advise not to allow empty string in text field nor zero default value for number field in table design).

For yes/no field, test for False (do not set DefaultValue property in table design):
`myR2![Supress] = IIf(myR2![Supress] = False, myR![Supress], True)`
or
`If myR2![Supress] = False Then myR2![Supress] = myR![Supress]`

Shorter code for import procedure. Modify with the above.

```
Do Until myR.EOF = True
    myR2.FindFirst ("Email = '" & myR![Email] & "'")
    If myR2.NoMatch = True Then
        myR2.AddNew
        myR2![Email] = myR![Email]
    Else
        myR2.Edit
    End If
    myR2![First Name] = myR![First Name]
    myR2![Last Name] = myR![Last Name]
    myR2![Position] = myR![Position]
    myR2![Company] = myR![Company]
    myR2![Industry] = myR![Industry]
    myR2![Size] = myR![Size]
    myR2![WebSite] = myR![WebSite]
    myR2![Location] = myR![Location]
    myR2![Office Number] = myR![Office Number]
    myR2![Mobile Number] = myR![Mobile Number]
    myR2![Source] = myR![Source]
    myR2![CFO-DEL] = myR![CFO-DEL]
    myR2![CFO-SPON] = myR![CFO-SPON]
    myR2![DP-DEL] = myR![DP-DEL]
    myR2![DP-SPON] = myR![DP-SPON]
    myR2![HR-DEL] = myR![HR-DEL]
    myR2![HR-SPON] = myR![HR-SPON]
    myR2![CIO-DEL] = myR![CIO-DEL]
    myR2![CIO-SPON] = myR![CIO-SPON]
    myR2![CMO-DEL] = myR![CMO-DEL]
    myR2![CMO-SPON] = myR![CMO-SPON]
    myR2![CISO-DEL] = myR![CISO-DEL]
    myR2![CISO-SPON] = myR![CISO-SPON]
    myR2![NIS] = myR![NIS]
    myR2![Supress] = myR![Supress]

    myR2.Update

    myR.MoveNext
Loop
```

Another, assuming recordsets have exactly same fields.

```
Dim myR As DAO.Recordset
Dim myR2 As DAO.Recordset
Dim fld As DAO.Field
Set myR = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Staging - Import", dbOpenDynaset)
Set myR2 = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("Contacts", dbOpenDynaset)
Do Until myR.EOF = True
    myR2.FindFirst "Email = '" & myR![Email] & "'"
    If myR2.NoMatch = True Then
        myR2.AddNew
        myR2![Email] = myR![Email]
    Else
        myR2.Edit
    End If
    For Each fld In myR.Fields
        If fld.Name <> "Email" And _
                (myR2.Fields(fld.Name) & "" = "" Or myR2.Fields(fld.Name) = False) Then
            myR2.Fields(fld.Name) = fld
        End If
    Next
    myR2.Update
    myR.MoveNext
Loop
```

Comment: Both of these would be perfect, I've already re-written my code using your first example (I can set each step as required) however I'm now getting that lovely 'Run-time error 3077' due to the line: myR2.FindFirst ("Email = '" & myR![Email] & "'") or if I swap to use the other code for a test it produces the same error in the same line: myR2.FindFirst "Email = '" & myR![Email] & "'" which has kind of irked me as this expression worked previously for locating/adding new emails

Comment: Try explicitly declaring both recordsets as DAO. My code fails if I don't but I get different error.

Comment: I'll try that, found the reason is some emails incorrectly have the ' character in resulting in the code to stop at that record. Easy fix, I've cleared the import data manually