# How do I update a single field of a single record with data from another table with VBA in MS Access

Tags: vba, database, ms-access, timestamp, record

In MS Access, I have a table called "Products". It contains quality testing parameters, as well as fields for "Part_No" and "Last_Test_Date". The "Last_Test_Date" field being the last time that the specific product was tested.

I have another table (Trend001) that is live updated with the actual test data from a hydraulic test machine, as well as the "Part_No" being tested and a current "Time_Stamp".

I would like to update the "Last_Test_Date" of the specific "Part_No" being tested with the "Time_Stamp" from the "Trend001" table.

That way the user knows the last time that the Part was tested.

I found this on Stackoverflow, but I don't know enough about the language to apply it to my project.

[Updating existing records and adding new records in table (MS Access VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50041105/updating-existing-records-and-adding-new-records-in-table-ms-access-vba)

'''

```
Public Sub UpdateExistingRecords()
    On Error GoTo ErrTrap
    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblTempData", dbOpenSnapshot)
    Set rsCommon = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblCommon", dbOpenDynaset)

    Dim idx As Long
    For idx = 1 To rs.RecordCount
        If ExistsInCommon(rs![Item ID]) Then
            If Not Update(rs) Then
                MsgBox "Failed to update.", vbExclamation
                GoTo Leave
            End If
```

'''

Answer (score 1):

You don't need VBA to do the update, just use a SQL update. This SQL will update all the parts in the Products table that exist in the Trend001 table.

```
UPDATE Products INNER JOIN Trend001 ON Products.Part_No = Trend001.Part_No
SET Products.Last_Test_Date = Trend001.Time_Stamp;
```

PLEASE - Remember to back up your database before running this update. A small typo could delete your data.