# Updating existing records and adding new records in table - only one record being updated (MS Access VBA)

Tags: vba, ms-access, insert-update

I recently read this post: [Updating existing records and adding new records in table (MS Access VBA)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/50041105/14951449)

A well thought out and elegant solution, but in my implementation, only the first record of the tblTempData table gets added (or updated if existing) to the tblCommon table.

Full code from the original post was:

```
Option Explicit

Private rsCommon As DAO.Recordset

Public Sub UpdateExistingRecords()
    On Error GoTo ErrTrap

    Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
    Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblTempData", dbOpenSnapshot)
    Set rsCommon = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tblCommon", dbOpenDynaset)

    Dim idx As Long
    For idx = 1 To rs.RecordCount
        If ExistsInCommon(rs![Item ID]) Then
            If Not Update(rs) Then
                MsgBox "Failed to update.", vbExclamation
                GoTo Leave
            End If
        Else
            If Not Add(rs) Then
                MsgBox "Failed to add.", vbExclamation
                GoTo Leave
            End If
        End If
        rs.MoveNext
    Next

Leave:
    If Not rs Is Nothing Then rs.Close
    If Not rsCommon Is Nothing Then rsCommon.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set rsCommon = Nothing
    Exit Sub

ErrTrap:
    MsgBox Err.Description, vbCritical
    Resume Leave
End Sub

' Exists - 'Assumes Id is String
Private Function ExistsInCommon(ByVal Id As String)
    ExistsInCommon = DCount("*", "tblCommon", "[Item ID] = '" & Id & "'") > 0   
End Function

' Update
Private Function Update(rs As DAO.Recordset) As Boolean
    With rsCommon
        .FindFirst "[Item ID] = '" & rs![Item ID] & "'"
        If .NoMatch Then Exit Function
        .Edit
        ![Item Description] = rs![Item Description]
        ![Material Number] = rs![Material Number]
        ![User] = rs![User]
        ![Supplier] = rs![Supplier]
        ![Current Status] = rs![Current Status]
        ![Remarks] = rs![Remarks]
        .Update
        .MoveFirst
    End With
    Update = True
End Function

'Add
Private Function Add(rs As DAO.Recordset) As Boolean
    With rsCommon
        .AddNew
        ![Item Description] = rs![Item Description]
        ![Material Number] = rs![Material Number]
        ![User] = rs![User]
        ![Supplier] = rs![Supplier]
        ![Current Status] = rs![Current Status]
        ![Remarks] = rs![Remarks]
        ![Item ID] = rs![Item ID]
        .Update
    End With
    Add = True
End Function
```

On further review I think there is a problem with the record count code for the tblTempData

```
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset

Set rs = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_kpi_data_temp", dbOpenSnapshot)
Set rsCommon = CurrentDb().OpenRecordset("SELECT * FROM tbl_kpi_data_leonardo", dbOpenDynaset)

Dim idx As Long
For idx = 1 To rs.RecordCount
```

This is returning 1 for me, when there are many more records in my tblTempData. If I substitute rs.RecordCount with a fixed value (for test purposes) I get the number of records I hardcoded with the fixed value added or updated as expected.

Any ideas?

Many Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Open rs as a *dynaset* and do a *MoveLast* and *MoveFirst* to obtain the record count.

Or, use the much simpler method with a query:

[Update and Append Records with One Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29267266/access-compare-two-tables-and-update-or-insert-data-in-first-table/29272782#29272782)